# Where do I find the source of a 'hook' in order to alter its output?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, hook, buddypress

Basic question.  There's a hook I want to alter and I have no idea where to find it.  Here's the code I'm working with.  The hook in specific is **'bp_before_member_header_meta'**

"

```
/**
 * BuddyPress - Users Header
 *
 * @package BuddyPress
 * @subpackage bp-default
 */

?>

<?php do_action( 'bp_before_member_header' ); ?>


<div id="item-header-content">
    <div class="auther-part">
        <div id="item-header-avatar">
            <a href="<?php bp_displayed_user_link(); ?>">
                <?php bp_displayed_user_avatar( 'type=full' ); ?>
            </a>
        </div><!-- #item-header-avatar -->

        <div class="auther-sidebar">
        <div id="item-meta">

            <div id="item-buttons">

            </div><!-- #item-buttons -->
            <?php do_action( 'bp_before_member_header_meta' ); ?>
            <?php do_action( 'bp_member_header_actions' ); ?>
```

Comment: Use a debugger, put a breakpoint on the line, then step into the function.

Comment: what do you want to do with it? finding the source of the hook doesn't matter, as usually any output/functionality happens to whatever functions that uses the hook.

Comment: @dan it would be nice, but "Use a debugger" is often easier said than done in PHP.  This isn't java and the server is often not local, possibly shared with no root access.

Comment: @kennypu, I'm clueless as to how this works.  All I know is that if I remove the hook, a chunk of things for which the CSS I want to alter disappears.  So I know somehow the hook is displaying them...the question is how??  I want to add div classes to some of those items so I can style them.

Comment: other places in the system there will be calls to add_action('bp_before_member_header_meta', 'some function') that provide the code for that do_action to run.  See my answer for a start on how to find them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a global array called $wp_filter that contains the invocations of actions and filters, so if you look in $wp_filter['bp_before_member_header'] you will get the current invocations of that action.

You can also use your IDE or grep to look for occurrences of add_action in code.  This doesn't always find them since the names are sometimes built by code.  I spent half an hour today looking for an action in Shopp that was built that way.

Edit:
The other side of the action-filter world is found in plugin.php functions do_action and  apply_filters.  this is the code that actually runs actions and filters, so you can look for calls to this if you want to know where a filter is run.  It takes the filter name as an argument and runs all the matching filters in the order specified.  It looks like you already know where these are.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to modify what that particular hook outputs, you should be able to use `add_filter()`, and add a filter directly to that hook.

Comment: You may need to remove the existing action first, eg wpautop almost always needs replacement, not just addition.